# AWS ECS & Nginx - Change from Http to Https is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

Hi I deployed my website. Everything worked find. Then I changed from http to https and now I get a blank white page or 502 502 Bad Gateway. I think the problem is in my nginx.conf.

I deploy my frontend and backend in the same task in the same service on AWS ESC.

Here are my ports:

```
Http->80
Https->443
Client Port 8080
Backend Port 4000
```

This is my nginx.conf originally before I changed to https (which worked):

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 60000;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}


http {
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush      on;
    tcp_nodelay     off;
    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version  1.0;
    gzip_comp_level    5;
    gzip_min_length    256;
    gzip_proxied       any;
    gzip_vary          on;
    gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/x-component;

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $upstream_addr '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name mydomain.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log compression;
                
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
            expires -1;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /graphql {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/graphql;
        }

        location /subscriptions {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/subscriptions;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        location /refresh_token {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/refresh_token;
            proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
            proxy_pass_header Authorization;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
            expires 1M;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            expires 1y;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

        location /static/ {
            root /var/www;
        }
    }
}
```

I made many changed to my nginx.conf and nothing worked. I verified my domain with AWS.
Here some changes I made:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name mydomian.com
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        listen [::]:443;
        server_name mydomian.com
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log compression;
                
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```

I'm using a load-balencer to terminate SSL.

Comment: Are you already using an AWS load balancer? If so, it's easier to just terminate SSL there, so you don't have to deal with it in your ECS services.

Comment: Yes I did. If I visit the domin it is a verified https.

Answer (score 0):

I focused on the nginx.conf but the conf is fine. I'm using websocket which caused the problem:

```
const host = window.location.host;
`ws://${host}/subscriptions`

so I added a s: 
`wss://${host}/subscriptions`
```

For 2 days I tried everything in the nginx.conf and I just had to add a s.
I'm super stupid because I did't checked the console for errors.